# WP7 Application update

Tags: windows-phone-7

I recently created an app for windows phone 7 and in final stage of development lets assume that its version is 1.0.. I can check if any update is available(eg. v1.1) through my website which returns a json. And if an update is available the user can download and install the update.

How do i setup it to automatically update it's version. i.e user just need to click OK if it prompts for an update and no need to go to marketplace..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having determined that there is an update for the user, you could inform the user, and then show the [`MarketplaceDetailTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394017%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to enable the user to update the application.

**NOTE:** To show the details for the current application, you do not need to specify a value for the **ContentIdentifier** property.

Comment: Just another add on to this here, when using the windows phone you can scan those weird bar codes.....well find your app published online and when you scan it it will have the direct link to your app in the marketplace. Combined with the directory of it and the Above answer i believe it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to update apps is to use the Windows Phone Marketplace, where updating apps is a integrated part of it.

So, no, you can't do what you're trying to do.